# How to print the variables represent instead of the variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

is there a way to print out a variables represent instead of the variable?
Let me illustrate you the idea:

```
E=[4,19,0,17,8]
G=[4,13,8,18,17]
F=[4,18,0,8,19]
D=[4,13,0,19,8]
lag = [E, G, F, D]
lcode = [4,19,0,17,8]

for i in lag:
    if i == lcode:
        print "This is", i
```

And I want the print to say: "This is E"... and not: "This is [4,19,0,17,8]"

Comment: Use a `dict` to store your lists of numbers rather than different variables.

Comment: Generally, objects don't have any idea what names you have bound them to. In any case, what if `lag` was `[[4,8,15], G, F, D]`? What would it print for the first unnamed list?

Comment: I keep having to post this link today... [keep your data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Comment: i have doubts is lag values are string right?['E' ...so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use idea of dictionary. You can do something like:

```
mydict = {"E":[4,19,0,17,8],"G":[4,13,8,18,17],"F":[4,18,0,8,19],"D":[4,13,0,19,8]}

for key,value in mydict.iteritems():
    if value == lcode:
        print "This is %s" %(i)
```

iteritems() breaks the dictionary elements to key value pairs, e.g key : value :: "E" : [4,19,0,17,8].

If you want to search which all lists contain a given `element`:

```
for key,value in mydict:
    if element in value:
        print "Element in %s " %(key)
```

so if element is 4, the program will print:

```
Element in E
Element in G
Element in F
Element in D
```

Comment: I think this will fail with something like "Unknown object/symbol E" or similar error.

Comment: Yes you are right, I just realized. Thanks for poiting out!

Answer (score 4):

This is how it can be done using a `dict`

```
items = {"E": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "G": [1, 12, 13, 15] }
search = 4
for key, values in items.iteritems():
    if search in values:
        print key
```

Output: E

Answer (score 0):

without creating a Dict, u can try this

```
import sys

    E=[4,19,0,17,8]
    G=[4,13,8,18,17]
    F=[4,18,0,8,19]
    D=[4,13,0,19,8]

    lcode = [4,19,0,17,8]

    modname = globals()['__name__']
    modobj  = sys.modules[modname]

    lag = ["E","G","F","D"]

    for name in lag:
        if lcode ==  getattr(modobj, name):
            print name
```

output: E